# Find unique text in comma delimited string in array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I convert this formula to work on an array.  I get an error when trying to add arrayformula()

```
join(", ",unique(transpose(split(regexreplace(B2,",\s*","⌛"),"⌛"))))
```

**Values**

B2: three, one, two, three, three, one

B3: three, one, two, three, three, one

B4: three, one, two, three, three, one

```
arrayformula(join(", ",unique(transpose(split(regexreplace(B2:B4,",\s*","⌛"),"⌛")))))
```

error given is Function SPLIT parameter 1 value should be non-empty.

The values I am trying to get outputted if I place the equation in C2, for example would be
C2: three, one, two

C3: three, one, two

C4: three, one, two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(B2:B,lambda(z,if(z="",,join(", ",unique(split(z,", "),1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a few questions, if you dont mind. The z represents each cell in B2:B, and does the ,1 make this case-sensitive?  Finally, why doesnt the arrayformula above work?

Comment: `1` is for unique function to work across on horizontal axis, the join() in the original formula is being applied to the whole array range in one go whilst it should be applied to each row individually once uniques are obtained.

Comment: I think one issue with this is that it will insert a comma between every word even if there is a phrase. I am going to ask as a separate question building onto this one.

Comment: use `split(z,", ",0)` in place of `split(z,", ")` within the formula & see how it goes.